# Error when calling a method from separate Python file

Tags: python, file, class, import

I am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game in Python, where I use two separate files. Each has different code and separate classes, which I am trying to call. However, each time I try to do so, I receive this error:

```
def __init__(self, letter): super().__init__(letter)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Why does this happen? I have imported the right files (as below) and used the code (under that) to call it.

```
from player import NormalPlayer, ComputerPlayer
```

--

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x_player = NormalPlayer("X")
    o_player = ComputerPlayer("O")
    ttt = TicTacToe()

    play(ttt, 
        x_player, 
        o_player, 
        print_game = True)
```

I haven't included it, but if you need me to provide all my code from both files, please let me know. If you know what my error is from this code, however, please let me know. Thank you!

```
# Recognise the player as an object, with a specific letter (X or O)
class Player:

    # Set the player's letter (noughts or crosses)
    def __init__(self, letter): self.letter = letter

    # Turn-based system
    def get_move(self, game): pass

# Use the inheritance of classes to create a computer player that uses the 'Player' class
class ComputerPlayer:

    # Set the computer's letter with teh super class
    def __init__(self, letter): super().__init__(letter)

    # Turn-based system, get a random move from all open possibilities
    def get_move(self, game):
        choice = random.choice(game.open_moves())
        return choice

# Use the inheritance of classes for the user object that uses the 'Player' class
class NormalPlayer:

    # Set the user's letter with the super class
    def __init__(self, letter): super().__init__(letter)

    # Turn-based system, get the player's movement choice
    def get_move(self, game):

        # Player's choice must first be verified
        verified = False

        # The spot value of the move the player wants to make
        value = None

        # Ask for the player's move
        while not verified:
            choice = input(self.letter + "\s turn. Which spot do you want to play? ")

            # Check if the player's choice is valid...
            try:

                # Turn the input into an integer
                value = int(choice)

                # If the spot value is not available, catch the error and tell the player
                if value not in game.open_moves():
                    raise ValueError

            # ...if it is, then announce it
            except ValueError:

                # If the choice was invalid, have the player decide their move again
                print("The spot value is not valid. Please choose another spot.")

        return value
```

Comment: Also, it seems some people have downvoted this post. I'm not sure as to why that is, as I've provided the necessary information, and have received a response. If a person can understand my question and answer it, why is it being downvoted? It is clear and provides the code that I am using. If you downvoted, please let me know what I can do to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not specifying which class you are inheriting from. To use inheritance, you do `class ClassName(ClassToInheritFrom)`.

So your file would look like:

```py
# Recognise the player as an object, with a specific letter (X or O)
class Player:

    # Set the player's letter (noughts or crosses)
    def __init__(self, letter): self.letter = letter

    # Turn-based system
    def get_move(self, game): pass

# Use the inheritance of classes to create a computer player that uses the 'Player' class
class ComputerPlayer(Player):

    # Set the computer's letter with teh super class
    def __init__(self, letter): super().__init__(letter)

    # Turn-based system, get a random move from all open possibilities
    def get_move(self, game):
        choice = random.choice(game.open_moves())
        return choice

# Use the inheritance of classes for the user object that uses the 'Player' class
class NormalPlayer(Player):

    # Set the user's letter with the super class
    def __init__(self, letter): super().__init__(letter)

    # Turn-based system, get the player's movement choice
    def get_move(self, game):

        # Player's choice must first be verified
        verified = False

        # The spot value of the move the player wants to make
        value = None

        # Ask for the player's move
        while not verified:
            choice = input(self.letter + "\s turn. Which spot do you want to play? ")

            # Check if the player's choice is valid...
            try:

                # Turn the input into an integer
                value = int(choice)

                # If the spot value is not available, catch the error and tell the player
                if value not in game.open_moves():
                    raise ValueError

            # ...if it is, then announce it
            except ValueError:

                # If the choice was invalid, have the player decide their move again
                print("The spot value is not valid. Please choose another spot.")

        return value
```